# OpenCPU or Plumber for creating web services in R?

Tags: r, web-services, opencpu, plumber

I'm trying to create a web service for My R Script that takes a CSV as an input and does analytics on it and then returns it. I am a complete beginner at this and have found out a couple of ways for doing this would be to use OpenCPU or Plumber. Is there any advantage of choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

OpenCPU is surely a good option. But, as you mentioned above you are a beginner, thus I will suggest you use Plumber. Plumber is less complex to understand, and it surely is quite powerful to read CSV files and run analytics smoothly.